# Coq: How to prove if statements involving strings?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I have a `string a` and on comparison with `string b`, if equals has an `string c`, else has `string x`. I know in the hypothesis that `fun x <= fun c`. How do I prove this below statement? `fun` is some function which takes in `string` and returns `nat`.

```
fun (if a == b then c else x) <= S (fun c)
```

The logic seems obvious but I am unable to split the if statements in coq. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand.  What is arith? where does it come from?  In your English text, you write that c and x have different types, but for the if then else statement to be well typed they need to have the same type.

Comment: @Yves: Edited the question. I just wanted to keep my question simple without having too many definitions atop.

Comment: I am still missing where the notation "a == b" comes from.  This notation does not seem to be introduced in the String library from Coq.  On the other hand, that library has a sting_dec function.  Is it what you use?

Comment: @Yves. Yes, I used the string_dec function.

Comment: Please post *self-contained* (including relevant imports), *valid* code when you ask a question. This doesn't even parse.

Comment: @gallais:  I wanted to get an idea without putting too much complexity into the question. Two of the fellow members understood and got back. Kindly don't downvote a question unless it's the only option you have.

Comment: It wouldn't add any complexity to it, quite the contrary. Case in point: you had to answer 2 additional questions to clarify what it was that you wanted to know.

Comment: Interestingly enough, there is the `[mcve]` shorthand for this link: [mcve]. This means it's a common problem here. I think your question would only become better if you provided a self-contained example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can write an if-then-else statement, it means that the test expression `a == b` is in a type with two constructors (like `bool`) or (`sumbool`).  I will first assume the type is `bool`.  In that case, the best approach during a proof is to enter the following command.

```
case_eq (a == b); intros hyp_ab.
```

This will generate two goals.  In the first one, you will have an hypothesis

```
hyp_ab : a == b = true
```

that asserts that the test succeeds and the goal conclusion has the following shape (the *if-then-else* is replaced by the *then* branch):

fun c <= S (fun c)

In the second goal, you will have an hypothesis

```
hyp_ab : a == b = false
```

and the goal conclusion has the following shape (the *if-then-else* is replaced by the *else* branch).

```
fun x <= S (fun c)
```

You should be able to carry on from there.

On the other hand, the `String` library from Coq has a function `string_dec` with return type `{a = b}+{a <> b}`.  If your notation `a == b` is a pretty notation for `string_dec a b`, it is better to use the following tactic:

```
destruct (a == b) as [hyp_ab | hyp_ab].
```

The behavior will be quite close to what I described above, only easier to use.

Intuitively, when you reason on an *if-then-else* statement, you use a command like `case_eq`, `destruct`, or `case` that leads you to studying separately the two executions paths, remember in an hypothesis why you took each of these executions paths.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looking exactly for `case_eq`. I really appreciate your detailed explanation. :)

Answer (score 3):

Let me complement Yves answer pointing out to a general "view" pattern that works well in many situations were case analysis is needed. I will use the built-in support in math-comp but the technique is not specific to it.

Let's assume your initial goal:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Variables (T : eqType) (a b : T).
Lemma u : (if a == b then 0 else 1) = 2.
Proof.
```

now, you could use `case_eq` + `simpl` to arrive to next step; however, you can also match using more specialized "view" lemmas. For example, you could use `ifP`:

```
ifP : forall (A : Type) (b : bool) (vT vF : A),
      if_spec b vT vF (b = false) b (if b then vT else vF)
```

where `if_spec` is:

```
Inductive if_spec (A : Type) (b : bool) (vT vF : A) (not_b : Prop) : bool -> A -> Set :=
    IfSpecTrue : b -> if_spec b vT vF not_b true vT
  | IfSpecFalse : not_b -> if_spec b vT vF not_b false vF
```

That looks a bit confusing, the important bit is the parameters to the type family `bool -> A -> Set`. The first exercise is "prove the `ifP` lemma!".

Indeed, if we use `ifP` in our proof, we get:

```
case: ifP.
Goal 1: (a == b) = true  -> 0 = 2
Goal 2: (a == b) = false -> 1 = 2
```

Note that we didn't have to specify anything! Indeed, lemmas of the form `{ A 
} + { B }` are just special cases of this view pattern. This trick works in many other situations, for example, you can also use `eqP`, which has a spec relating the boolean equality with the propositional one. If you do:

```
case: eqP.
```

you'll get:

```
Goal 1: a = b  -> 0 = 2
Goal 2: a <> b -> 1 = 2
```

which is very convenient. In fact, `eqP` is basically a generic version of the `type_dec` principle.

Comment: Where does the name "view" come from and what is the general intuition one should have about views? I mean, they are not rewriting equations or inversion lemmas.

Comment: I am not sure where does the name "view" come from, likely there are better names, maybe "specification". I call it view as for some operators (ie <=) you have different "views" on the case analysis. The intuition behind a "view" is that it will do case analysis on some construction, _populating the context properly_ as to continue the proof. This is sometimes not trivial and usually saves quite a bit amount of time.