# What is difference between `destruct` and `case_eq` tactics in Coq?

Tags: coq

I understood `destruct` as it breaks an inductive definition into its constructors. I recently saw `case_eq` and I couldn't understand what it does differently?

```
1 subgoals
n : nat
k : nat
m : M.t nat
H : match M.find (elt:=nat) n m with
    | Some _ => true
    | None => false
    end = true
______________________________________(1/1)
cc n (M.add k k m) = true
```

In the above context, if I do destruct `M.find n m` it breaks H into true and false whereas `case_eq (M.find n m)` leaves H intact and adds separate proposition `M.find (elt:=nat) n m = Some v`, which I can rewrite to get same effect as destruct.

Can someone please explain me the difference between the two tactics and when which one should be used?

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823301/how-to-do-cases-with-an-inductive-type-in-coq/6828451#6828451

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The first basic tactic in the family of `destruct` and `case_eq` is called `case`.  This tactic modifies only the conclusion.  When you type `case A` and `A` has a type `T` which is inductive, the system replaces `A` in the goal's conclusion by instances of all the constructors of type `T`, adding universal quantifications for the arguments of these constructors, if needed.  This creates as many goals as there are constructors in type `T`.  The formula `A` disappears from the goal and if there is any information about `A` in an hypothesis, the link between this information and all the new constructors that replace it in the conclusion gets lost.  In spite of this, `case` is an important primitive tactic.

Loosing the link between information in the hypotheses and instances of `A` in the conclusion is a big problem in practice, so developers came up with two solutions: `case_eq` and `destruct`.

Personnally, when writing the Coq'Art book, I proposed that we write a simple tactic on top of `case` that keeps a link between `A` and the various constructor instances in the form of an equality.  This is the tactic now called `case_eq`.  It does the same thing as `case` but adds an extra implication in the goal, where the premise of the implication is an equality of the form `A = ...` and where `...` is an instance of each constructor.

At about the same time, the tactic `destruct` was proposed.  Instead of limiting the effect of replacement in the goal's conclusion, `destruct` replaces all instances of `A` appearing in the hypotheses with instances of constructors of type `T`.  In a sense, this is cleaner because it avoids relying on the extra concept of equality, but it is still incomplete because the expression `A` may be a compound expression `f B`, and if `B` appears in the hypothesis but not `f B` the link between `A` and `B` will still be lost.

**Illustration**

```
Definition my_pred (n : nat) := match n with 0 => 0 | S p => p end.

Lemma example n :  n <= 1 -> my_pred n <= 0.
Proof.
case_eq (my_pred n).
```

Gives the two goals

```
------------------
n <= 1 -> my_pred n = 0 -> 0 <= 0
```

and

```
------------------
forall p, my_pred n = S p -> n <= 1 -> S p <= 0
```

the extra equality is very useful here.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46434503/1809211) I suggested that the developer use `case_eq (a == b)` when `(a == b)` has type `bool` because this type is inductive and not very informative (constructors have no argument).  But when `(a == b)` has type `{a = b}+{a <> b}` (which is the case for the `string_dec` function) the constructors have arguments that are proofs of interesting properties and the extra universal quantification for the arguments of the constructors are enough to give the relevant information, in this case `a = b` in a first goal and `a <> b` in a second goal.

Comment: Note that `destruct` has a variant `destruct H eqn:H0` which also remembers an equality.

Comment: Also note that there's a simple wrapper `destruct_with_eqn H`, which automatically generates a fresh name for the equality.