# reduce match with conditions on natural numbers in coq

Tags: coq

Given the hypothesis

```
H0 : n <> 0
```

How can I reduce the term

```
...
if match n with
     | 0 => false
     | S m' => n =? m'
   end
then
...
```

In the goal?

Answer (score 1):

You should also look at the answer to the [following question on destruct and case_eq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46440349/what-is-difference-between-destruct-and-case-eq-tactics-in-coq)

the tactic `destruct n as [|p]` will lead you in the right direction.  It will generate two goals, one with

```
H0 : 0 <> 0
==========
 if false then ...
```

one with

```
H0 : S p <> 0
==========
  if n =? p then ...
```

the first goal should be solvable by `case H0`.