# When destructing fixpoint, add hypothesis without simplifying

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Suppose I have to prove the following lemma:

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.EqNat.

Lemma myLemma: forall m,
  if beq_nat m 0
  then m = 0
  else m <> 0.
```

and I proceed this way:

```
Proof.
  intro.
  destruct (beq_nat m 0).  (* [1] *)
  - (* [2] *)
  - (* ???? Can't do anything *)
Qed.
```

then, at point [1], the `destruct` proceeds by case analysis, first `beq_nat m 0` is replaced by `true` in the `if` which is simplified to the goal `m = 0`, without additional hypothesis (at point [2]).

My question is: instead of splitting the goal, replacing and simplifying, is there a way to split the goal, and adding the corresponding case as an hypothesis ?

That is, at point [2], instead of having the following:

```
m : nat
______________________________________(1/1)
m = 0
```

I'd like to have:

```
m : nat
true = PeanoNat.Nat.eqb m 0
______________________________________(1/1)
if PeanoNat.Nat.eqb m 0 then m = 0 else m <> 0
```

and to proceed myself to the following of the proof.

(N.B.: this is a very dummy mwe, I know that there are other ways to finish here, my point is not to finish this particular proof, but to have a method to get an hypothesis from a destruct).

Comment: Do you specifically want to leave `beq_nat m 0` alone in the goal? (Anton's answer gives you a couple ways to retain an equality, but the thing you're destructing is still simplified.)

Comment: @TejChajed Thanks, at first I missed this "how to avoid simplification" part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `destruct (beq_nat m 0)` you can use

```
destruct (beq_nat m 0) eqn:Equation_name.
```

or

```
case_eq (beq_nat m 0).
```

`destruct ... eqn:E` is like `case_eq ...; intros E`. You can find out more about the differences between `destruct` and `case` having read this [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46440349/2747511).

The first two options simplify things, but we can do something like this to avoid the simplification:

```
remember (beq_nat m 0) as b eqn:E; rewrite E; destruct b.
```

This third option will give you a proof state like this

```
m : nat
E : true = PeanoNat.Nat.eqb m 0
============================
if PeanoNat.Nat.eqb m 0 then m = 0 else m <> 0
```

for the first subgoal.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted, thanks for the detailed answer.